# How to use css selector in object from HtmlResponse

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I'm currently developing an application using `Scrapy`.

I want to get some value using `CSS selector` out of `def parse`, So I create a `HtmlResponse` object first and tried to get some value using `css()`, But I can't get any value...

Within `def parse`, I can get the value in the same way.

What should I do if it is outside of def parse?

---

Here is the code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse


class SampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'sample'
    allowed_domains = ['sample.com']
    start_urls = ['https://sample.com/search']

    my_response = HtmlResponse(url=start_urls[0])

    print('HtmlResponse')
    print(my_response)

    h3s = my_response.css('h3')

    print(str(len(h3s)))

    print('----------')

    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):

        print('def parse')
        print(response)

        h3s = response.css('h3')

        print(str(len(h3s)))
```

Console display：

```
HtmlResponse
<200 https://sample.com/search>
0 # <- I want to show '3' here
----------
def parse
<200 https://sample.com/search>
3
```

---

**update**

The program I want to finally create is the following code:

[ (Note) The code below does not work for reference ]

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse


class SampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'sample'
    allowed_domains = ['sample.com']
    start_urls = []
    response_url = 'https://sample.com/search'

    my_response = HtmlResponse(url=response_url)
    categories = my_response.css('.categories a::attr(href)').getall()

    for category in categories:
        start_urls.append(category)

    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
        
        pages = response.css('h3')

        for page in pages:
            print(page.css('::text').get())
```

Python 3.8.5

Scrapy 2.5.0

Comment: What kind of value you want to use and where do you wanna use the value in scrapy? Could you please more specify about it?

Comment: @Murat Demir, I want to use a value that can be handled as a `response` in `def parse`. (In the case of the above code, if I select `h3`, the number of elements will be `3`). And I want to use that value before def parse is called.

Comment: @Tio see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52187714/how-to-get-response-from-scrapy-request-without-callback) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42240802/printing-response-from-scrapy-request)

Comment: you can get the value because the `HtmlResponse` you created is empty,in parse the response is created by scrapy downloader,so it has content in response variable.the response you created just has only url,not doing anything to fetch content.so why you want something outside the parse,tell us you actually want we can help you

Comment: @nay, I updated my question with the reference code I want to make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know what do you mean,your start url is the basic domain,but you also want to fetch all category page to extract `h3`.
in scrapy you can extract data and follow new links in the same parse method,here is a example.

```py
import scrapy


class SampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'sample'
    allowed_domains = ['sample.com']
    start_urls = ['https://sample.com/search']

    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):

        print('def parse')
        print(response)

        pages = response.css('h3')

        #extract data at here
        for page in pages:
            print(page.css('::text').get())
            yield page.css('::text').get()
        
        #follow new links here
        categories = response.css('.categories a::attr(href)').getall()
        for category in categories:
            yield scrapy.Request(category,callback=self.parse)
```

you can read [scrapy document](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#following-links) for more information